# Invalid operator '$size' in aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I got the following piece of code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('ipOfServer')
db = client.admin
db.authenticate('login', 'password',
source='admin_')
heh = list(db.events.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": {"status": 'start'}},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$eventName", "players": {"$addToSet": "$uid"}}},
        {"$project": {"_id": 1, "Count": {"$size": "$players"}}}
    ]))
print(heh)
```

and this is worked for the original programmer who wrote and tested it [code result while testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRiah.png). But when I try to run it I'm getting this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: exception: invalid operator '$size'
```

I'm using mongo version 2.4.14 and python 2.7.12 with the sublime text editor. Could anyone suggest ways to solve this problem, it would be appreciated.

Comment: should be correct, no errors heret. can you post more code?

Comment: Zaharie Which type of code you want? I didn't wrote any code for this aggregation because it gave me an error. Or you want an example from mongo?

Comment: you wrote this code in a python script .py?

Comment: Yes of corse. I'm intelligent enough for that.

Comment: Please post everything what you have, so we can track it. Over here, I have no error, I can't help you from this data.

Comment: added pretty everything i have that is connected to aggregate

Comment: Why is your PyMongo version? Are you sure you are not running MongoDB 2.4?

Comment: check db.version() . I think you are running pymongo 3.3 not MongoDB 3.3

Comment: ooouu, you right. It is 2.4.14. And is there any functions or operators with the same functional as $size?

Comment: @M.Basman start your message with the `@` sign following by the user name as I did when you want talk to someone.

Comment: @SSDMS thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) array aggregation operator is new in MongoDB 2.6 and you are actually running MongoDB 2.4.

I suggest you upgrade your MongoDB server to at least 3.0. But if for some reason you don't want to upgrade now, you will need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) the "players" array and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) by "_id" then return the count using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum) accumulator operator.

```
heh = list(db.events.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": {"status": 'start'}},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$eventName", "players": {"$addToSet": "$uid"}}},
        {"$unwind": "$players"},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "Count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    ]))
```